# AngularJS when I click a link I want to filter an array

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working with a website using PHP and AngularJS, I have a product list and a droplist that has some links which will allow the user to filter products by type(electric guitars, acoustic guitars, etc...) is there any way to do a function that filters the ng-repeat to only show products whose type are the selected one?

This is what I currently have:

```
<article class="producto" ng-repeat="product in dbproducts | filter:prodsearch">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="products/img/{{product.Imagen}}" alt="{{product.Marca + ' ' + product.Modelo}}">
        <p class="product-model">{{product.Marca + ' ' + product.Modelo}}</p>
        <span class="product-price">{{product.Precio | currency: '€'}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="check">
        <div class="paygroup">
            <p class="price" ng-bind="product.Precio | currency: '€'"></p>
            <button class="buy"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>{{'BUTTON_BUY' | translate}}</button>
            <p>{{'BUTTON_AVAILABLE' |translate}}: {{product.Unidades_disponibles}} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
        <p>Test, hola,  {{ $index }}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="close fa fa-times fa-inverse"></span>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, what I did was:

- Adding another pipe in ng-repeat called filter: producttype
- Added a $scope.producttypevariable;
- Changed the value of the variable each time I clicked on the links in the dropdown so it would filter by type. This:

  `<li ng-click="producttype='electrica'"><a>Guitarras eléctricas</a></li>`

Thanks for your help and tips, and sorry if this method is not the best, I learnt angularjs by myself(i'm not a good self-learner).

Answer (score 0):

So If I get your code right, you already have a pipe filter in your ng-repeat:

`| filter:prodsearch`

So I guess somewhere in an input directly or in your controller you hare binding a user input to the variable "prodsearch" and the ng-repeat is live filtered.

In the same way, you can have buttons, whether they are in a droplist or not, which click action would be assigning a certain text to the "prodsearch" variable.

Comment: prodsearch is to search by product name(which is in a search input on my navbar), I want to filter products by type when I click on a link that is on a dropdown menu in the navbar.

Comment: and what about ng-show="product.type ==variable_with_selected_type" in the <article>??

Answer (score 0):

A `filter` is what you want. Another way is Using a copy array of products to show and writing a function which update your array of products. This function receives a type and just add related products to showing items.

Something like this:

**Controller**

Call this function on `ng-change` of drop down

```
$scope.filters = ["all", "electric", "guitars", "acoustic", "guitars"];
$scope.selectedFilter = "all";

$scope.filterProds() {
  if ($scope.selectedFilter == "all") {
    $scope.dbproductsToShow = $scope.dbproducts;
  } else {
    $scope.dbproductsToShow = [];
    $scope.dbproducts.forEach(function(itm) {
      if (itm['type'] == filter) {
        $scope.dbproductsToShow.push(itm);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And in your **Html**

```
 <select ng-model="selectedFilter" ng-options="filter in filters" ng-change="filterProds()"></select>

 <article class="producto" ng-repeat="product in dbproductsToShow">
```